# Python recursive path finder for binary tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, tree, binary-tree

I'm trying to write a recursive function in python that given a binary tree and a node returns a string containing directions to the node. I've got close but my final return statement gives me the path plus the node (I don't need the node) i.e LRLR4.

here is my code so far:

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def join(item: object, left: Tree, right: Tree):
        tree = Tree()
        tree.root = item
        tree.left = left
        tree.right = right
        return tree

def path(tree: Tree, node: str, out: str=""):
    if not tree:
        return ""
    if tree.root == node:
        return tree.root
    res = path(tree.left, node)
    if res:
        return "L" + res    
    res = path(tree.right, node)
    if res:
        return "R" + res
```

Is there a way I can implement this without the node on the end of the string output?

Edit: added all actual code and the tree in question contains single letter strings for each node.

Comment: Hard to say without an [mre] but maybe change to `if tree.root == node: return ""`

Comment: Hi Johnny, thanks I tried that but it returns nothing instead. Sorry I'm new here, the function is all the code I have. Do you mean map out the tree and code it too for example?

Comment: Just realized you mean you need to see my class, sorry my bad. Updated post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write `path` -

```py
def path(tree, target):
  if not tree:
    return ""
  elif target < tree.root:
    return "L" + path(tree.left, target)
  elif target > tree.root:
    return "R" + path(tree.right, target)
  else:
    return ""  # tree.root equal to target; don't return node
```

We can make some more improvements to your `Tree` class though. See these assignments in `join`?

```py
def join(item: object, left: Tree, right: Tree):
    tree = Tree()
    tree.root = item
    tree.left = left
    tree.right = right
    return tree
```

It would be better if the `Tree` constructor takes these values as arguments -

```py
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, root, left = None, right = None):
        self.root = root
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def join(item, left, right):
      return Tree(item, left, right) # pass as arguments
```

Now the `join` function is redundant and can be removed -

```py
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, root, left = None, right = None):
        self.root = root
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    # no more need for `join`
```

Given `mytree` -

```py
#         g
#       /   \
#      /     \
#     d       m
#    / \     / \
#   b   f   j   q 
#  /         \
# a           k      

mytree = \
  Tree("g",
    Tree("d", Tree("b", Tree("a")), Tree("f")),
    Tree("m", Tree("j", None, Tree("k")), Tree("q"))
  )
```

```py
print(path(mytree, "f")) # LR
print(path(mytree, "k")) # RLR
print(path(mytree, "q")) # RRR
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help but this leads to a error: ```<ipython-input-94-1143305ac8b4> in path(tree, target)
      3     if not tree:
      4         return ""
----> 5     elif target < tree.left:
      6         return "L" + path(tree.left, target)
      7     elif target > tree.right:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'Tree ```

Comment: Just to add clarification my tree is comprised of single letter strings.

Comment: when you call `path` you need to supply a string for `target` then

Comment: surely that means I cannot use > & < operators?

Comment: you can use `<` and `>` as long as you compare elements of the same type

Comment: But Strings are compared lexicographically using the numeric equivalents of their characters. Also even with the node assigned to a string the error persists.

Comment: @Sinsinful sorry there was a mistake in the code. the comparisons are changed to `target < tree.root` and `target > tree.root`. i updated the post with a tested program.